# How to build node addon, so that it can be imported only by name, and not path

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

When I build a node add-on by creating a standard *binding.gyp* and running `node-gyp build`, the addon.node library is created in the subdirectory `build/{Release|Debug}/`. When I write tests or other javascript code to use this module, I have to give explicit path to the library location

For example,

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/addon')
```

However, I would like to do this by only specifying the module name and let node's module search for the library

```
var addon = require('addon')
```

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a module for that if you're okay with another dependency.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings

That will search all of the possible build output locations automatically, including debug and release directories.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is setting `require()` and having the module in the `node_modules` folder or having the module in a `node_modules` folder in one of the parent directories.

Node uses the `require()` method with no path defined as an indicator to look for the module in the `node_modules` directory. Unless its an native module.

Its detailed in the docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).